# Phantom JS weakmap Error

Tags: angular, webpack, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

im using webpack, angular 2, karma 0.13, jasmine 2.4.1

i have no reference to weakmap in my application. could not resolve with latest version of phantomjs

***>           START:

> ```
> ts-loader: Using typescript@2.2.2 and C:\\tsconfig.json
> 26 04 2017 12:48:25.002:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9999/
> 26 04 2017 12:48:25.033:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
> 26 04 2017 12:48:27.939:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 6_yGicfWc30o_UC2AAAA with id 19438296
> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WeakMap
>   at C:/src/tests.entry.ts:9
> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
>   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WeakMap
>   at C:/src/tests.entry.ts:9***
> ```

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WeakMap
  at C:/src/tests.entry.ts:9
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WeakMap
  at C:/src/tests.entry.ts:9

Comment: Have you tried upgrading Karma to 1.7.0? This has helped other people with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using a package which makes use of weakmap.  According to this issue on phantom.js (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13652), Phantomjs is not currently keeping up with webkit core.

Recommendations are to select another headless browser or use babel-polyfill.

Comment: Just to point out that PhantomJS development has been suspended and will never support ES6 specifications: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344